# Replace ajax error and success functions with alternates passed to parent function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written the following JavaScript class:

```
var DbObject = Class.extend({
  init: function(classname, id){
      // do some init stuff
  },
  send: function(isError){
       if(isError){
           // do something else
       }
       else if(!uploading){ // global 
          var obj =$.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(this));
          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "ajaxManager.php",
                data: {data:obj},
                success: function(response) { 
                   response.success=true;
                   if(response.callback) window[response.callback](response);
                   console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                  alert(err.Message);
                }
          });
       }
       else{
           console.log('waiting....');
           var $this =this;
           setTimeout(function(){$this.send(); }, 2000);
       }
  }
});
```

Right now, I use the class like this:

```
var object = new DbObject('PageSettings', rowId);
object.send();
```

I'd like to be able to also use it like this:

```
var object = new DbObject('PageSettings', rowId);
object.send(false, {
    success: function (response) {
        // some alternate code to run instead of the ajax `success: function`
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // some alternate code to run instead of the ajax `error: function`
    }
});
```

Where the `{ success: //...., error: //...}` supplied in the call to `.send()` should replace the `{ success: //...., error: //...}` in the ajax call it makes.

**What would be the proper way to accomplish this?**

Comment: what is the purpose of the unused `isError` parameter? - oh, and there is no hint of `promise` in the code, so you should remove that tag

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry, it is used, Ijust left that part out for SO, but Ill edit to be more clear

Comment: as long as it has purpose, it's all good :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complete natural for promises.  All you have to do is return the promise from the ajax call and your caller can then just use the promise directly without having to know what happened internally:

```
var DbObject = Class.extend({
    init: function (classname, id) {
        // do some init stuff
    },
    send: function (isError) {
        if (isError) {
            // handle synchronously, but still return a promise so
            // the caller gets the same behavior
            $(someSelector).show(); 
            return $.Deferred().resolve(false).promise();
        } else if (!uploading) { // global 
            var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(this));
            return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "ajaxManager.php",
                data: {
                    data: obj
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('waiting....');
            var self = this;
            return $.Deferred(function(def) {
                // now set up delayed execution
                setTimeout(function () {
                    def.resolve();
                }, 2000);
            }).then(function() {
                // link this into the existing promise chain
                return self.send();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And, sample usage:

```
var db = new DbObject('PageSettings', rowId);
db.send().then(function (result) {
    // success here
}, function (err) {
    // error here
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this approach. In the `if (isError)` block, If I wanted to do something like set an error message and return. Would the following be correct `$(someSelector).show(); return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();`?

Comment: @DelightedD0D - yes, that would work.  You may want to resolve with a particular value so the caller's `.then()` handler can distinguish that condition from the return value of the actual Ajax call (assuming the caller needs to know the difference).  I will add that to my answer.

Comment: To that end would the following be correct `return $.Deferred().resolve('wasError').promise();` and late in the `.then` block checking with `if(result==='wasError'){ // do something...}`

Comment: Instead of polling, could you not maintain a rolling promise chain?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - this already does use a promise chain.  It could only stop polling if the OP had an event or promise when the `uploading` flag was changed.  With what is disclosed in the question, there is no info about either that could be used.

Comment: Yes agreed, more knowledge about the mysterious `uploading` would be good.

Answer (score 2):

Change the send function like this:

```
send: function (isError,handlers) {
    if (!handlers) handlers = {};

    if (!uploading) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(this));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "ajaxManager.php",
            data: {
                data: obj
            },
            success: handlers.success || function (response) {
               ....
            },
            error: handlers.error || function (xhr, status, error) {
                ....
            }
        });
    } else {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: The `send` should then be called like `object.send(is_error, succes, error);` right? It looked to me like he intended the send to take just 2 parameters, where the 2nd parameter contains both succes and error in a dictionary.

Comment: @KentMuntheCaspersen Yea. That's why I added the last sentence in the post. He can do it however he wants. I have provided just the concept.

Comment: Thank you @YavorIvanov I was unaware of that syntax. I edited your answer a touch so as to maintain the `{ success: //...., error: //...}` syntax. But that was exactly what I needed

Comment: @DelightedD0D No problem :). I edited it a little bit more, adding the validation `if (!handlers) handlers = {};`. It sets the value of handlers to an empty object, if there isn't one provided, or it has a falsy value. If this isn't there, it may throw an error that it's undefined here: `handlers.success || function (response)` and so on...

Comment: @YavorIvanov it works without it, but for clarity Ive' added it as well. Thanks again!